# Cloudformation metadata commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to learn Cloudformation.
Can someone please explain to me why `1-install-roles` is numbered with "1"?
What does this line do `"if not \"None\" EQU \"",`

```
Resource("WindowsServer") do
    Type("AWS::EC2::Instance")
    Metadata("AWS::CloudFormation::Init", {
  "config" => {
    "commands" => {
      "1-install-roles"    => {
        "command" => FnJoin("", [
  "if not \"None\" EQU \"",
  Ref("Roles"),
  "\" (powershell.exe add-windowsfeature ",
  Ref("Roles"),
  " -restart)"
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1- is prepended for ordering to ensure the command gets executed first. It's executed in alphabetical order. The if not \"None\" EQU \" bit is windows batch scripting. EQU is a comparison operator and means "equal".

Let's assume that the reference to Roles returns the string "Something", the command executed will be:

if not "None" EQU "Something" "(powershell.exe add-windowsfeature Something -restart)"

Comment: If I specify the sequence, will it wait until the first sequence finish before executing the next sequence?